# Array of Duration values in Framer Motion not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, framer-motion

I am trying to animate a piece of text to go across a box and then reappear on the opposite side it exits out of. When doing this I can get it to work using a linear animation, however that means there is a delay before it comes out of the other side again. If i want to make some of the animations duration 0 so it instantly goes to the other side of the box using an array of duration values the animation just breaks and nothing happens. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
"use client";
import { motion } from "framer-motion";
import React from "react";

const TextAnimation = () => {
  return (
    <div className="w-full overflow-hidden relative">
      <motion.p
        initial={{ x: "-50%" }}
        animate={{ x: ["100%", "-100%", "-50%"] }}
        transition={{
          duration: [0, 5, 0],
          repeat: Infinity,
          repeatType: "loop",
          ease: "linear",
        }}
      >
        Animations
      </motion.p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default TextAnimation;
```